# Logging details of an application usage

Tags: android

Is there any way where I can keep track of the application usability.I would have a tracker class which would keep record of all the interactions with the applications.

For Example:-

When I open a login application... when I enter username the tracker should detect that and store it, then when I press login button - tracker should detect and add that the " respective button was clicked"....

Comment: specify a bit more. and put your code what you have done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Analytic for tracking the Android app activities :

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/

or

http://www.cobub.com/products/cobub-razor/

Answer (score 0):

**Google analytics** is a great tool for generating reports on your app's performance after users have started using it.

Here are some features of Google Analytics are :

- Number of active users using their app
- Demographics of users
- Adoption and usage of specific features
- In-app purchases and transactions
- Number and type of application crashes

You can get started for it from [HERE](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/) also learn from [DEMO](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-enabling-google-analytics-to-gather-app-statistics/)